# Calling a function when using string interpolation

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets say I have a Javascript function that adds two numbers as follows

```
function addNumbers(a, b){
return a+b;
}
```

Then I want to output to the console the result of calling the function with two numbers. When using string concatenation I can do the following:

```
console.log('The sum of two numbers is' +
addNumbers(a, b));
```

However, my question is how do I call the function if I want to use string interpolation? Something like:

```
 console.log(`the sum of two numbers 
    is addNumbers(a, b)`);
```

Answer (score 3):

As always, the expression you want to output the result of evaluating goes between `${` and `}`.

```js
function addNumbers(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

const a = 4;
const b = 6;

console.log(`the sum of two numbers 
    is ${addNumbers(a, b)}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to is wrap the expression with `${}`

```
console.log(`the sum of two numbers is ${addNumbers(a, b)}`);
```

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (``)  (grave accent)
>   character instead of double or single quotes. Template literals can
>   contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly
>   braces (${expression})

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any expression inside of template literals (``) with a inside a $ and curly braces (${}).

Your example would look like this:

```
 console.log(`the sum of two numbers is ${addNumbers(a, b)}`);
```

See [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more information.